# ListView with match_parent doesn't respect weight of parent when filled with items. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 Listviews in 2 different LinearLayouts. The 2 linearlayouts are part of a more complex UI and the height of the 2 LinearLayouts is a weight value. 
The 2 Listviews inside just fill the parent (LinearLayout). All works fine until I begin to fill the ListViews with items. 
As I fill the first listView with lets say 10 items, the first listView begins to eat place and get place from the second listview so at the end the second listview occupies less space than the first. It's not a desired behavior. I need the ListView to be fixed.

Here is the code. Will omit not needed code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="9"
android:orientation="vertical" >
  ...
  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/secondPart"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="9.1"
  android:layout_weight= "9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Screen1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView 
                    android:id = "@+id/lvMain1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


     </LinearLayout>   

     <LinearLayout 
                    android:id = "@+id/timerContainer2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height = "0dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">


       ....

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id = "@+id/Screen2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:layout_height ="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

                 <ListView 
                    android:id = "@+id/lvMain2"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

the weightsum for the whole UI is defined and is 9.1

Comment: can you post the parent of these linearlayouts?

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Screen1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView 
                android:id = "@+id/lvMain1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

To:

```
  <ListView 
                android:id = "@+id/lvMain1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4.5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

I am not sure this will solve your exact problem but linear layout is not needed here.

Comment: Sorry. But this did not help.. Still as I fill the listview somehow the weight is no more respected.

Comment: sorry guy. it was my fault

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for time consuming.
It was my fault.

In code side I was setting the weight of the Screen1 and Screen2

and somehow I changed the width and height by code:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I wanted simply to change the weight:

```
params.weight = 4.5f;
```

But didn't put the right width and height in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want something like this:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seperator" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code:**

```
public class MYList extends Activity {

    ListView listTOP,listBottom;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo2);

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
        {
            data.add("Item "+(i+1));
        }

        listTOP = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listBottom = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        listTOP.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,data));
        listBottom.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,data));
    }

}
```